# The fastest possible method of parsing HTML document with Node.js and XPath

Tags: node.js, xpath, google-cloud-functions

I know that there are several such questions with answers but they were asked many years ago and as you know NodeJs packages are getting old very quickly and are no longer developed. Therefore, what is the fastest xPath package in NodeJs currently?

Time and resources are important here because it will be called in the Firebase function.

Comment: If you're prepared to wait a couple of weeks, Saxonica is almost ready to ship Saxon-JS on node.js. Don't know if it will be the fastest, but it will certainly be the most up-to-date, with full XPath 3.1 support. Talk to us offline if you'd like to work with us.

Comment: Maybe you should  have a look at : https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-html-parser